# how do i delete or edit a specific row of result from while loop?

Tags: php

I don't know how to fetch each specific id and add this to following query.

```
    $id = '';
    $del = '';
    $del .="<form action=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']." method='POST'>";
    $del .="<input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" /></form>";
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $del_sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=$id"; //i can't fetch id.
        $del_qry = mysqli_query($link, $del_sql);
    }
```

Following is the code to fetch and display data from mysql.

```
$display_list = ''; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $email = $row['email'];

        $display_list .= '<p>'.$id.'<br /> '.$name.'<br /> '.$email.' </p>'.'<p>'.$del.'</p>';

    }
```

Comment: Where do you create that form?

Comment: Check your SELECT query which is not visible here.

Comment: SELECT query is ok and display a result. But i want to add delete button for each row result.